# Tracking File Downloads with GA, jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, google-analytics, download

Is there any simple way of using Google Analytics to track downloads of a specific file? For instance, in my website I would like to have a link to

```
http://mydomain.com/resume
```

which would redirect to a PDF file with my resumé. My idea is to:

1. Use URL rewriting to automatically redirect http://mydomain.com/resume to http://mydomain.com/download.php?file=resume.pdf (or something along these lines).
2. Have `download.php` making `$(function() { _gaq.push(...); }` with the appropriate parameters so that the specific file is tracked as if it was a normal page.
3. Have `download.php` redirect the request to the specific `resume.pdf` file.

However, I have a few questions about this:

1. Would this whole process be as transparent to the user as placing a simple `<a href="resume.pdf">Click Me!` with no tracking at all? (I mean... no popups, no strange page redirections, etc)?
2. Would this allow for the file to be opened in the browser window, if its format is supported (for instance, pdf), or would a "Save File Dialog" appear instead?
3. Is this the only/simplest way to do what I would like to achieve? If not, how can I achive the same effect through simpler means?

Comment: FYI: The information is already available in your access logs, provided that you didn't disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Google Analytics is perceived to be a frontend-only thing, all it does is send a bunch of HTTP requests. In [Google Anayltics for Mobile Websites](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/mobileWebsites.html) they tell you about an option to send tracking events to GA from your server-side scripts. For that, simply download the gooogleanalyticsformobile.zip from [Mobile SDK Downloads](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/download.html). Therein you'll find the ga.php file showing how you can easily dispatch to GA.

With [php-ga](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) there seems to exist a complete framework for talking to Google Analytics. (Haven't used this, can't say if it's any good)

Now that you know you can call GA from your PHP, you can extend your download.php to issue a request to GA before outputting the file to download.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hotlink an image that executes some JavaScript, as that is a huge security flaw.

However, if you can figure out how to add a "View" in PHP, then you can just up the viewcount by 1 when the user asks for the page.

Basically, nothing client-side can happen when they view an image.

Answer (score 0):

GA has a solution for this, see [Tracking files](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55529)